# PHP - Replace string src value with data uri

Tags: php, arrays, string, data-uri

Good day.

I have an array which holds the data uri of an img.

```
$var =
array(
[0] => data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...
[1] => data:image/png;base64,Rw0KKGgoasWAA...
);
```

And I have a string.

```
$foo = '<p>test 7/31/2</p> <p>&nbsp;<img src="/media/1.png" alt="" /></p> <p><img src="/media/2.png" alt="" /></p>';
```

How can I replace the `src` in `$foo` with the data uri array in `$var`?

Result would be like.

```
$foo = '<p>test 7/31/2</p> <p>&nbsp;<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA..." alt="" /></p> <p><img src="data:image/png;base64,Rw0KKGgoasWAA..." alt="" /></p>';
```

Any ideas will do!

Comment: Not only would I use `<img src="<?php echo $arr[0]; ?>" alt="" />` ???

Comment: @ExtremsX I'll update my question, it's not clear, I noticed. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$images = [
    "/media/1.png" => 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...',
    "/media/2.png" => 'data:image/png;base64,Rw0KKGgoasWAA...'
];

$url = '<p>test 7/31/2</p> <p>&nbsp;<img src="/media/1.png" alt="" /></p> <p><img src="/media/2.png" alt="" /></p>';
$url = str_replace(array_keys($images), array_values($images), $url);
```

Comment: Yes, I could do something like this. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was tinkering the code. I added `array_combine` to it. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA',
    'data:image/png;base64,Rw0KKGgoasWAA'
);

$string = '<p>test 7/31/2</p> <p>&nbsp;<img src="'.$array[0].'" alt="" /></p> <p><img src="'.$array[1].'" alt="" /></p>';

echo $string;
```

Comment: I've updated my question's description, I apologize for the confusion!